# Data from file not displaying correctly when user is prompted

Tags: c++, console, return

I'm following some tutorials by TheNewBoston on C++
I am up to about the 70th tutorial and wrapping up, but I've encountered my first real problem. I had to create a bogus "items.txt" file for the tutorial, pretending these were items for a game. From there, the user would type in whether they wanted to return harmful items (*negative integers*), normal items (*return 0*) or helpful items (*positive integers*) assuming that these objects within the game would have an effect on the player's health.

My problem is that it doesn't always return the list of positive/neutral/negative integers. Sometimes it returns them, other times it will just set the value and discontinue working with them. I don't understand because I've checked my code and everything seems to be fine.

Here's my entire code:

```
int getWant();
void displayItems(int x);

//main function
int main () {

int whatTheyWant;

whatTheyWant = getWant();

while (getWant() != 4) {
    switch(whatTheyWant){
    case 1:
        displayItems(1);
        break;
    case 2:
        displayItems(2);
        break;
    case 3:
        displayItems(3);
        break;
    }
}

return 0;
}

//getWant function
int getWant(){
int choice;

cout << "1 - Regular" << endl;
cout << "2 - Helpful" << endl;
cout << "3 - Harmful" << endl;
cout << "4 - Quit Program" << endl;

cin >> choice;
return choice;
}

//display items function
void displayItems(int x)
{
ifstream itemFile("items.txt");
string name;
double power;

switch(x) {
case 1:
    while(itemFile >> name >> power) {
        if(power == 0){
            cout << name << ' ' << power << endl;
        }
case 2:
    while(itemFile >> name >> power) {
        if(power>0) {
            cout << name << ' ' << power << endl;
        }
    }
case 3:
    while(itemFile >> name >> power) {
        if(power<0)
            cout << name << ' ' << power << endl;
    }
    }
}
}
```

and here is my text file with the fake "items".

```
Flower 0
ShadowGrunt -20
Tree 0
Light -50
Darkfruit 25
ShadowPlant -10
Water 0
ShadowBat -5
Poison -20
Darkrain 2
TaintedBerries 10
Grass 0
```

as an example, if the user inputs "2", it should show all the positive items.
So the console would display:

> ```
> Darkfruit 25
> Darkrain 2
> TaintedBerries 10
> ```

or if they were to input "3", the console should show:

> ```
> ShadowGrunt -20
> Light -50
> ShadowPlant -10
> ShadowBat -5
> Poison -20
> ```

and so on.
Instead I'll get answers like Darkberries, then maybe ShadowBat, or Grass. I don't really understand but hopefully someone here can help me.
This is a completely useless program but I want to *understand* the reasons that this isn't functioning properly and learn from them.

Comment: in switch of the void displayItems(int x) is missing break!

Comment: Thank you!
I can't believe I forgot the break!
That's the second time I've used switches so... Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting your **whatTheyWant** variable to latest read value from getWant() function. Modify your **main** function code as follows :

```
//main function
int main () {

int whatTheyWant;

while ((whatTheyWant=getWant()) != 4) {
    switch(whatTheyWant){
    case 1:
        displayItems(1);
        break;
    case 2:
        displayItems(2);
        break;
    case 3:
        displayItems(3);
        break;
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This fixed a lot of my issue as well. Can you please explain to me a little bit on how this works? On the YouTube tutorial it worked for him just fine without doing this.